# iOS iphone formatting: What is best way to format page so it works on all screens?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, layout

I have looked at umpteen tutorials, google posts and questions on SO but am still struggling with best way to layout a page for an iPhone app.

Part of the problem is many of the tutorials and questions are old and discuss ways that may have been optimal at some time in past.

Now, in May 2015, what is best-simplest way to have things like textfields and images layout so they display properly in common iPhones i.e. iPhone 4, 5, 6 and 6Plus?

Is it necessary to use constraints?  I've gone down this road but found it very labor intensive?

Can you use blue lines as recommend in Stanford 193P tutorial?  Or is there any rule of thumb way to layout a picture or a text box so that it looks good in multiple formats i.e. some number of points or using blue lines.

Storyboard in Xcode 6.0 is now 600x600 from what I can tell so a lot of times what you lay out looks horrible in the simulator.  But the simulator is not an actual iPhone.

Thanks for any suggestions on right way to do this.

Comment: Constraints is the May 2015 way.  And yes, a nuisance to learn and something of a nuisance even after the topic has been learned.

Comment: I have just finished with the iOS 8 by tutorials book from Ray Wenderlich website. The first 4 or 5 chapters are great for learning how to use the interface builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially have two choices; constraints or frame math. Both have their benefits and detriments.

The benefit of layout constraints is that you can figure out universal relationships between subviews and their superview. (e.g. It's always 20 points from leading and trailing edges or it's always dead center x and y) Once you do that, you only need to write layout code once and it will work across all device screen sizes. Also, if you ever plan to support iPad or rotation on iPhone, the work it will take to support that functionality is minimal. Another huge benefit is that if a view's frame changes, it will take care of resizing and laying out all of its subviews for you so you can modify the size of a container for example and not have to reset all of it's children's frames manually.

Constraints are "more modern" than frame math and definitely Apple's preferred method.

The issue with constraints is that the code is more verbose. Views also depend on their superviews to lay themselves out. If everything is done correctly it works great. But if you make a mistake adding constraints to one view it has the potential to trash everything else that depends on it. Once you get everything figured out it does exactly what it advertises. But getting to that point can be, in my opinion, more complicated than setting frames explicitly since there are more moving parts.

Frame math still has it's place sometimes. It has the benefit of being fast and relatively concise. Back when iPhones all had the same sized displays it worked great and if you are laying out in a view with a guaranteed rect there's no reason to need to avoid setting frames.

The problem with frames is that you are expected to support all the devices that run iOS 8. If you are laying out with frames that means you could have to write 5 different sets of layout code to support 4s, 5, 6, 6+, and iPad and 5 more sets if you want them all to rotate. This isn't always tenable.

In the end it comes down whether or not your containing view has a guaranteed height and width. If the answer is yes (like laying out inside of a collection view cell with a static width and height for example), I would have no problem leaning towards frames. If not, auto layout is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is **AutoLayout**,in other words **Create constraints**

- You can change storyboard to device as you like by click here.

[image]

- You can use blue line as reference then let XCode auto create. But in this way,you are not always get right layout
- Also,you can create layout by here

[image]

- And you can create layout by Control + drag

[image]

By create layout,it is easy to place you views